Confusion about integral form of interaction potential in Dyson series
I'm reading through the Hamiltonian formulation of perturbation theory and am having trouble understanding how the integral form of the interaction potential is derived.
Consider a scalar field $\phi$ evolving with Hamiltonian $H=H_0+V(t)$ where $H_0$ is the free Hamiltonian and $V(t) = \int d^3xf(\phi(x,t))$ is the interaction potential where $f$ is some polynomial ($x$ will denote a spatial 3-vector throughout). Choose some reference time $t_0$ and denote the full time evolution operator as $S(t,t_0)$. Defining the free fields as:
$$\tag{1}\phi_0(x,t) = e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}\phi(x,t_0)e^{-iH_0(t-t_0)},$$
we get that:
$$\tag{2}\phi(x,t) = U^\dagger(t,t_0)\phi_0(x,t)U(t,t_0),$$
where $U(t,t_0)=e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}S(t,t_0)$. Differentiating $U$, we get that $i  \partial_tU=V_I(t,t_0)U$.
Now, both Schwartz and Peskin & Schroeder derive the explicit form of $V_I$ as:
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}V_I(t) = \int d^3x f(\phi_0(x,t)),
\end{equation}
and I simply don't understand how they get this. Peskin & Schroeder show that (equation 4.19 in their book):
$$\tag{4} V_I(t)=e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}V(t)e^{-iH_0(t-t_0)},$$
and then immediately deduce $(3)$, even though by $(2)$ this should only be the case if $$V_I(t)=U^\dagger(t,t_0)V(t)U(t,t_0).$$
Schwartz's derivation depends on the printing, but on the one I have (the 7th) he derives the expression (equation 7.33 in his book) that $$V_I(t)=e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}V(t_0)e^{-iH_0(t-t_0)},$$ which, by $(1)$, indeed yields $(3)$ but is equally dubious to me since $i\partial_tS(t,t_0)=H(t)S(t,t_0)$, not $H(t_0)S(t,t_0)$. There is no reason for $V(t_0)$ to show up when differentiating $U$. At first I thought it was a typo but apparently it was changed to $t_0$ from $t$ in the 3rd printing and included in the 2nd printing's errata.
As far as I can tell, $(4)$ is the correct expression and $V_I$ should be
$$V_I(t)=e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}V(t)e^{-iH_0(t-t_0)}=\int d^3x f(e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}\phi(x,t)e^{-iH_0(t-t_0)}),$$
which obviously ruins the whole point of expressing everything in terms of the free fields. What am I missing?

In short, it is important (for us all) to distinguish between operators defined in various pictures, and how these definitions relate to each other.  P&S define the interaction in equation 4.12, which reads $H_{int} = \int d^3 x\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4(x)$.  This is before (time-dependent) interacting fields have been introduced, and so the equation should be interpreted in terms of the free Klein-Gordon field operator $\phi(x)$ in the Schroedinger picture, not the time-dependent interacting field $\phi(x,t)$ in the Heisenberg picture.  My understanding of the discussion in chapter 4 is that P&S choose an arbitrary time $t_0$ where either (1) the (already interacting) field operators and their momenta are expanded in hypothetical free-particle ladder operators that satisfy appropriate commutation relations and whose dynamics is subsequently traced, or (2) the interaction is turned on suddenly.  In either case, the question then is how the hypothetical erstwhile free-particle ladder operators evolve in the Heisenberg picture of the new Hamiltonian (with interaction defined in terms of the original Schroedinger-picture field.)
